# Can't create a constant using mem::size_of inside a function on a sized generic type (E401)

Tags: generics, rust, constants, sizeof

I have a Rust program where I've been trying to use const functions as an alternative to macros to generate various constants at compile-time (which has been going great so far), but I've just hit a roadblock where the snippet below won't compile because `size_of` takes a generic parameter, and the compiler says I can't use the one from the function's signature:

```rust
const fn _IOC<T:Sized>(dir:u32, code:u8, nr:u8) -> u32 {
    // use of generic parameter from outer function (E0401)
    const size: usize = ::core::mem::size_of::<T>();

    (dir  << 30) | ((size as u32) << 16) | ((code as u32) << 8) | ((nr as u32))
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let myioctl = _IOC::<[u8; 65]>(3, b'H', 0x06);
        assert_eq!(myioctl, 0xC0414806);
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
error[E0401]: can't use generic parameters from outer function
 --> src/lib.rs:3:48
  |
1 | const fn _IOC<T:Sized>(dir:u32, code:u8, nr:u8) -> u32 {
  |               - type parameter from outer function
2 |     // use of generic parameter from outer function (E0401)
3 |     const size: usize = ::core::mem::size_of::<T>();
  |                                                ^ use of generic parameter from outer function
```

I'm not sure I understand why [this specific error](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0401) would apply to the code above. Should I regard this as a compiler edge-case that isn't currently supported by the language or is there a way to make this work that I'm not seeing?

Comment: You could perhaps [report an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/new) to improve the error message in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be declaring `size` as a `const`. It should just be a regular immutable variable:

```rust
let size = ::core::mem::size_of::<T>();
```

[**Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a1cfbd3d310785082c0a7b1b122ec68)

Comment: Ah, I figured it would count as a `const` given the value would be known at monomorphisation, but I guess I just misunderstand how `const fn` works. Thank you.

Comment: OMG, I've been thinking for a month that this just is some odd edge case in Rust I don't understand. That compiler error is awful!

Comment: Opened an issue to track it: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/79955